# In MySQL partitioning a table, how is the DIV used here as part of the HASH partition definition?

Tags: mysql, performance, hash, partitioning, database-partitioning

I was reading about partitioning and somewhere I read the following example:
`HASH (id DIV 1000000)`
This can be used to create a new partition for each million rows inserted (id is the primary key).
But I don't understand how this id DIV 1000000
This is not modulo right? So how is the hash used here?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that is designed to put the first million rows in the first partition, the second million in the second, ... and eventually wrap around.

That sucks.

You will get no performance benefit.  It probably cannot do partition pruning either on INSERT or on SELECT.

Let's go back to the drawing board.  Why are you thinking about using PARTITIONing?  There are very few use cases for which PARTITION is of any benefit.  I have summarized tips here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint .  That blog also shows how to deal with the most common use case, namely a time-series where you purge 'old' rows.

Comment: I know what this does. It creates a new partition every 1000000 rows. What I am asking is how does this happen. I don't understand the `DIV` inside the `HASH`

Comment: BTW very interesting link

Answer (score 0):

The DIV function performs Integer Division, e.g. 108/10 = 10.8 where 108 DIV 10 = 10.

ID DIV 1000000 will return 0 for the first 1000000 records, 1 for the next 1000000 and so forth.

HASH(ID DIV 1000000) returns a HASH of the returned integer.